DigiPot Actual Resistance Range?
I'm currently looking at a the AD8400 digipot:

I'm guessing that the minimum resistance is determined by the wiper resistance? But besides that, does it mean that worst case, my digipot will have a minimum resistance of 100 ohm?



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Equivalent circuit.

It's telling you that no matter where the wiper is you're going to have to allow for 53 to 100 Ω in series with the "wiper".
If W is feeding into a high impedance circuit then it won't matter. As the input impedance of the following circuit reduces then it will matter.


simulate this circuit
Figure 2. Various loading conditions. (a) Open-circuit. (b) 10 kΩ load. (c) 1 kΩ load. Wiper is at max (k = 1 on CircuitLab simulator) in each case.
The simulator shows the effect of RW on VW (the wiper voltage).
You can see that the effect is more pronounced on the low impedance, 1 kΩ circuit.

... does it mean that worst case, my digipot will have a minimum resistance of 100 ohm?

It means that worst case you will always have 100 Ω in series with the wiper and you may have to account for this when sourcing current from or sinking current into the potentiometer.

What is a potentiometer? It's a resistance track with a fixed resistance - 1.2 kΩ in the figures above. The wiper moves along the track and, if A and B are at different potentials (voltages) the wiper will output a potential which varies from A to B depending on the pot position. It is a "potential divider", hence the name, "potentiometer".
In a physical potentiometer there will be some resistance between the wiper solder tag and the point of contact on the track. This is usually quite low but in the digital pot it is high enough to have the possibility of creating a problem. Once you know what it is you can allow for it.

Got it. So is 0 ohms the minimum wiper resistance?

No the datasheet says it's typically 53 Ω and maximum of 100 Ω. The wiper can go all the way to the bottom but the resistance between W and B will be > 53 Ω.

So when the wiper is at the bottom, the typical resistance of the entire digipot will be typically 53?

No, A-B will be 1.2 kΩ, A-W will be 1.2k + 100 = 1.3 kΩ. W-B will be 100 Ω.

See the update.

100Ω is the datasheet guaranteed maximum wiper resistance
a) Over the entire temperature range (especially up to 125°C)
b) With a 5.0V power supply.
Since the 'typical' maximum wiper resistance almost doubles with a 3V supply (and there is no guaranteed maximum) you might assume that the wiper resistance could be more than 200Ω with a 3V supply.
If the resistance behaves as on a typical analog switch then it will increase around 30-40% at 125°C vs. 25°C. So we might assume at room temperature the worst-case is not quite as bad as 100Ω if the supply voltage is 5V.
When the wiper is at either end, in rheostat mode, the total resistance to the end it is close to is the wiper resistance.
It's not clear to me exactly what voltage is assumed to be on the wiper in rheostat mode. The current is stated. You can expect some variation with voltage, especially if the supply voltage is low.
Btw, not your question, but note that this particular model lacks any reset circuit so the power-up state won't be at 50% (or anything else that can be guaranteed).
Analog has application notes which can augment the compressed information on their datasheets. Worth looking them up.

TL;DR: Yes 100Ω, but only with a 5V supply.


You are looking at a 1k digipot so 1k is the maximum resistance, or 1600 ohms including the tolerance, but not including the wiper resistance, which adds it up to 1700 ohms.
The 100 ohm is only the worst case maximum for the wiper connection, when digipot is powered with 5V supply.

Thank you for the response Will the minimum be 100 ohms then?

@itisyeetimetoday No, it reads in the datasheet that 100 ohms is the maximum. The minimum is unspecified.

You can use the digipot in rheostat mode (left) or in potentiometer mode (right):

Rheostat mode:
The digipot's resistance has a wide tolerance: 0.8-1.6 kOhm, and a large tempco of 700ppm/°C. This makes the variable resistance mode quite inaccurate. In addition the wiper resistance is in series so it sets the minimum resistance value, it also has a wide tolerance and depends on supply voltage. At Vcc=5V it has a maximum of 100 ohms and a typical of 53 ohms.
If the digipot is part of a feedback loop, then this inaccuracy is less of a prolem. By "feedback loop" I mean, if your microcontroller has a way to constantly measure the output of your circuit, then adjust the digipot to get the desired results. One example would be automatic gain control.
Potentiometer mode:
In this mode the pot is used as a voltage divider, and the two resistors in the divider are on the same chip so they have matching tolerance and drift, which cancel out, so it is much more accurate. Integral nonlinearity is 6LSB (6/256=2.3%), and drift is only 25ppm/°C. Therefore this mode is also usable for things like calibration, where the pot is set once.
In potentiometer mode, wiper resistance is of course in series with the wiper, but not with the pot. It matters only if current flows through the wiper, as it will create a voltage drop. If you connect it to a high impedance output, or buffer it with an opamp, then current will be low enough that the 100 ohms won't matter. In potentiometer mode, if you set it to zero, it will connect the wiper to the low end of the pot which is ground in the schematic above, so the output will be ground in series with the wiper resistance. So there is no "minimum resistance" problem, as the output of the digipot really goes from zero to VCC.
